# How does where clause in One to many relation work in java

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two tables A and B.

```
@Table(name = "table_a")
@Data
public class A {


    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> bs;
}
@Table(name = "table_b")
@Data
public class B {


    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer b_id;

    @Column(name = "a_id)
    private Integer a_id;
    
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", insertable = false, updatable =   false)
    private A a;
}
```

Now the problem is when i try to run JPQL version of this below query

```
select a.* from table_a a
  inner join table_b b on a.id = b.a_id 
  where b.status = -1;
```

it returns all the rows even with status other than -1, i.e. it returns all the rows in table_b associated with id of table a. I know i am using it incorrectly, what should i do so i can query on status present in table_b

Comment: Is this supposed to be a raw SQL query or a JPQL query?

Comment: Looking at the query, it looks like you are missing the alias `a` for `table_a`. Could you try running `select a.* from table_a a inner join table_b on a.id = b.a_id where b.status = -1;`

Comment: JPQL, basically the issue is that i have oneToMany realtionship with table_b, now in sql i get result when i try querying by doing join with table_b and do b.status =-1. But here in JPQL it gives all the rows and doesn't filter on the basis of status parameter.  I have used this exact query
select a.* from table_a a inner join table_b on a.id = b.a_id where b.status = -1;, still in JPQL all the rows are being fetched

Comment: Do you have a [MRE], e.g. a github repository, that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

I build a reproducer, it is [available at `github.com`](https://github.com/turing85/spring-join).

### Technical cleanup

During this, I noticed the following things:

1. The entities `A` and `B` are missing the `@Entitiy`-annotation
2. The entities `A` and `B` are missing an `@Id` annotation on the primary key
3. The attribute `a_id` in entity `B` is superfluous

This leads to the following restructuring of entities `A` and `B`:

`A.java`:

```
package de.turing85.spring.join;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
@Data
public class A {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore // This is for testing only so Jackson does not run into an endless recursion
  private List<B> bs;
}
```

---

`B.java`:

```
package de.turing85.spring.join;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
@Data
public class B {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "status")
  Integer status;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  A a;
}
```

---

### Query construction

With these changes in place, we can tackle the actual issue. The [syntax for a join in JPQL (`jakarta.ee`)](https://jakarta.ee/learn/docs/jakartaee-tutorial/current/persist/persistence-querylanguage/persistence-querylanguage.html#_queries_that_navigate_to_related_entities) is as follows:

```
SELECT <root-alias-name> FROM <root-type-name> <root-alias-name>
INNER JOIN <root-alias-name>.<field-to-join-on> <join-alias-name>
WHERE ...
```

Translated to our example, this leads to

```
SELECT a FROM A a
INNER JOIN a.bs b
WHERE ...
```

Notice that we wrote `a.bs b`. We access a collection, but address it as singular. From a query point o f view, the collection is transparent for us, we only see the singular `B`-entities (imagine the query being a loop that is executed for each `B` in `bs`).

Armed with this knowledge, we can formulate our `WHERE` condition, which is then straight forward:

```
SELECT a FROM A a
INNER JOIN a.bs b
WHERE b.status = -1
```

We can now define this query in our `ARepository`:

```
package de.turing85.spring.join;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Integer> {
  @Query("""
      SELECT a FROM A a 
      INNER JOIN a.bs b
      WHERE b.status = -1
      """)
  List<A> findByBStatusMinusOne();
}
```

### Testing

With a `Controller.java` to access the entities:

```
package de.turing85.spring.join;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(Controller.PATH)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Controller {
  public static final String PATH = "as";
  private final ARepository repository;

  @GetMapping
  List<A> getAllAs() {
    return repository.findAll();
  }

  @GetMapping(path = "bMinusOne")
  List<A> getAllAsWithBMinusOne() {
    return repository.findByBStatusMinusOne();
  }
}
```

and some test data:

```
DELETE FROM table_b;
DELETE FROM table_a;

INSERT INTO table_a(id)
VALUES
    (0),
    (1),
    (2);
INSERT INTO table_b(id, status, a_id)
VALUES
    (0, -1, 0),
    (1, 0, 1),
    (2, -1, 1),
    (3, 0, 2);
```

We can now run `./mvnw clean package` to run the integration tests:

`ControllerTest.java`:

```
package de.turing85.spring.join;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DisplayName("Controller Tests")
@Sql({ "/data.sql" })
class ControllerTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  private Integer port;

  @Container
  @ServiceConnection
  static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:16.1-alpine3.19");

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Get All A's")
  void getAll() {
    // @formatter: off
    RestAssured
        .when().get("http://localhost:%d/%s".formatted(port, Controller.PATH))
        .then().assertThat()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
            .body("size()", is(3))
            .body("collect { it.id }", hasItems(0, 1, 2));
    // @formatter: on
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Get All A's with at least one B in status -1")
  void getBMinusOne() {
    // @formatter: off
    RestAssured
        .when().get("http://localhost:%d/%s/bMinusOne".formatted(port, Controller.PATH))
        .then().assertThat()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
            .body("size()", is(2))
            .body("collect { it.id }", hasItems(0, 1));
    // @formatter: on
  }
}
```

which verify that the query works as expected. Note that the integration tests use testcontainers and thus need a docker- or docker-compatible environment to be executed.

---

### Remark

I propagated the database-entity 1:1 to the rest-endpoint. This was done for brevity. Notice in particular that I had to `@JsonIgnore` the `bs` in `A`. If we do not do this, jackson will run into an infinite recursion due to the bidirectional relation. For a production-grade solution, I recommend a segregation of database- and response-entities.